# PHP string replace firstname with first letter in first name

Tags: php, regex

I have i string in my PHP-code which looks like this

```
Bokad av Anna Göransson 14:45 - 15:45
```

Now i want to replace "Anna" with "A.". How can i do that using regexp and PHP?

Comment: Why do you think you need regular expressions for this simple str_replace?

Comment: How do you tell what the first name is?

Comment: Is that just an example string? If so you need to elaborate on the 'rules' of the contents of the string for us to be able to help you.

Comment: http://old.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something different if the string is dynamic and subject to change.

```
$string = "okad av Anna Göransson 14:45 - 15:45";
$names = explode(" ",$string);
$names[2] = strtoupper($names[2][0]).".";
$string = implode(" ",$names);
```

Comment: `strtoupper(substr($names[2],0,1)).".";` can also be written as `strtoupper($names[2][0]).".";`

Comment: To clarify what Braveyard said: this solution relies upon the name in question (`Anna`) being the 3rd word (array index 2). In my limited experience, there are always cases where this won't be true.

Comment: @FrankFarmer : You're right, thanks for the tip.I will update my answer .

Answer (score 0):

You can do use something like this

```
$foo=str_replace('Anna', 'A',$foo);
```